# mobile number validation using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want mobile number in format
+91(or any other country code)-9999999999(10 digit mobile number).

I have tried `/^\+[0-9]{2,3}+[0-9]\d{10}`, but its not working please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Solution in short:

```
// should return an array with a single match representing the phone number in arr[0]
var arr = '+49-1234567890'.match(/^\+\d{1,3}-\d{9,10}$/); 
// should return null
var nullVal = 'invalid entry'.match(/^\+\d{1,3}-\d{9,10}$/);
```

Longer explanation:

- `/` start regex
- `^` try to match from the beginning
- `\+` match a + sign
- `\d{1,3}` match a digit 1 to 3 times
- `-` match a dash
- `\d{9,10}` match 9 or 10 digits
- `$` force the matching to be only valid if can be applied until string termination
- `/` finish regex

Knowing what the regex does, might let you modify it to your own needs

Sometimes it is good to ignore any whitespaces you come across. `\s*` matches 0 or n whitespaces. So in order to be more permissive you could let users input something like `' + 49 - 1232345 '`

The regex to match this would be `/^\s*\+\s*\d{1,3}\s*-\s*\d{9, 10}\s*$/` (just filled the possible space locations with `\s*`)

Other than that: I warmly recommend mastering regexes, because they come really handy in many situations.

Comment: Just try the provided regex out in the console of a browser: `'+49-1234567890'.match(/^\+\d{1,3}-\d{9,10}$/)` (Firefox: `Ctrl+shift+K`)

Comment: It will match only strictly 3 numbers as prefix and 10 numbers as whole number. But won't accept `+33-1234567890` (2nrs for prefix) or +123-123456789 (9 nrs for number).
To make it flexible you should do `/^\+[0-9]{1,3}\-[0-9]{9,10}$/` and since `[0-9]` is the same as `\d` aka. a digit you arrive to the formula provided by me

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting a dash in the number (which your format shows), there is nothing in your regex to match it: is the second plus in the regex meant to be a dash?

```
^\+[0-9]{2,3}-[0-9]\d{10}
```

Also note that:

1. some country codes are single digit (eg. 1 for North America, 7 for Russia), these will not be matched
2. I doubt the local part of all mobiles everywhere is always 10 digits (eg. it won't be enough in countries with large populations as mobile ownership grows)

Comment: In France, mobile numbers are 9 digits.

Comment: I didnt get u..i want simple country code(1 to 3 digit)-(10 or 9 digit number)

Comment: Its nt taking any regex except[+91]..m nt gtng wts the prb

Comment: @anupnavare 1. Please write English: heavy use of Text Speak like abreviations will make it much harder for those that don't speak text speak or English as a second language (there is plenty of space for text in comments). 2. You first range will need to be `{1,3}` to allow one to three digits.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write the following:

```
var pattern=/^(0|[+91]{3})?[7-9][0-9]{9}$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\+[0-9]{2,3}-[0-9]+
```

Try this. This matches a `+` in the beginning, two or three numbers for the country code, followed by a `-` followed by any number of numbers

Comment: you might want to add an extra backslash where the backslash is, so that Javascript would read it as a literal backslash

Answer (score 1):

Use the mask function

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("#phone").mask("999-999-9999",{placeholder:" "});   
});
```

look here http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/control-data-entry-formats-with-input-masks-HA010096452.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For mobile validation please try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mobile number validation using regex</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value;
        var pattern = /^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/;
        if (pattern.test(mobile)) {
            alert("Your mobile number : "+mobile);
            return true;
        }
        alert("It is not valid mobile number");
        return false;

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
Enter Mobile No. :
<input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="validate();" />
</body>
</html>
```